# Dynamic angular.js orderby button ng-click

Tags: html, angularjs, sql-order-by

Here is the code:

```
<button ng-init="propriety: 'name'" ng-click="propriety == 'name' ? propriety = 'price' : propriety = 'name'"></button>
<div ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy: propriety">
  <li>item.name - item.price</li>
</div>
```

What am i missing?

Edit 1:
Changed to ng-click, still not working.

Edit 2:
Added ng-init.

Edit 3:
Fixed missing double quotation mark. Still not working.

Comment: `on-click` should be `ng-click`

Comment: are you missing the double quotation marks after `'name'`

Answer (score 0):

Change

From

```
<button ng-init="propriety: 'name'" ng-click="propriety == 'name' ? propriety = 'price' : propriety = 'name'></button>
```

To

```
<button ng-init="propriety: 'name'" ng-click="propriety == 'name' ? propriety = 'price' : propriety = 'name'"></button>
```

Comment: can you post your json

Comment: how do i get my json?

Comment: whatever you have inside items ! console.log($socpe.items)

Comment: Wondering, what is the difference.. what was wrong with initial one.. I thought `ng-init` was wrong.. but that won't solve OP's problem...

Comment: the answer i posted have extra  missing double quotation mark

Answer (score 0):

try that

```
ng-init="propriety = 'name'"
ng-click="propriety = propriety == 'name' ? 'price' : 'name'"
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<button ng-init="propriety= 'name'" ng-click="propriety == 'name' ? propriety = 'price' : propriety = 'name'">
```

working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/modar/tbxm3Lrd/5/)